# Python Heatmaps (Basic and Complex)

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, heatmap, bokeh

What's the best way to do a heatmap in python (2.7)? I've found the [heatmap.py](https://github.com/keenerd/rtl-sdr-misc/blob/master/heatmap/heatmap.py) module, and I was wondering if people have any advice on using it, or if there are other packages that do a good job.

I'm dealing with pretty basic data, like `xy = np.random.rand(1000,2)` superimposed on an image.

Although there's another thing I want to try, which is doing a heatmap that's scaled to a different heatmap. E.g., I have

```
attempts = np.random.rand(5000,2)
successes = np.random.rand(500,2)
```

And I want a heatmap of the successes relative to the density of the attempts. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) is a pretty widely-used library for making nice-looking plots, and has a [heatmap function](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html). Seaborn uses matplotlib under the hood.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

xy = np.random.rand(1000,2)
sns.heatmap(xy, yticklabels=100)
```

[image]

Regarding your second question, I'm not sure what you mean. But my advice would be to create a numpy array or pandas dataframe of "successes [scaled] relative to the density of the attempts", however you mean that, and then pass that scaled array or dataframe to `sns.heatmap`

Comment: I have x, y data for all observations, and x, y data for observations of class 1. I want to do a heatmap of the observations of class 1 that scales the heat of a point to the heat of the point for the total population.

Think 1st graph as males per country, while 2nd graph is males per capita per country.

Comment: is there a downside to my suggestion of producing a `scaled_dataset` and then passing that to `sns.heatmap`? I think that's a better approach than trying to get the heatmap function to dynamically scale it for you

Comment: I'll try that, I'm just making sure that you understood what I was trying for before I did, in case there was a different way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot very complex heatmap using python package PyComplexHeatmap: https://github.com/DingWB/PyComplexHeatmap
https://github.com/DingWB/PyComplexHeatmap/blob/main/examples.ipynb

[image: example2]
[image: PyComplexHeatmap]

Answer (score -1):

The most basic heatmap you can get is an image plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xy = np.random.rand(100,2)
plt.imshow(xy, aspect="auto")
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that using more points than you have pixels to show the heatmap might not make too much sense.

There are of course also different methods to draw a heatmaps and you may go through the [matplotlib example gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) and see which plot appeals most to you.